# Preventing Pubnub cipher key from being viewed

Tags: javascript, pubnub

To enable message-level encrpytion in Pubnub, one would include the cipher key when instantiating PubNub on the client.

```
var pubnub = PUBNUB({
    publish_key: 'my_pubkey',
    subscribe_key: 'my_subkey',
    cipher_key: 'my_cipherkey'
 });
```

The PubNub docs then state:

> Never let your cipher key be discovered, and be sure to only exchange it / deliver it securely. On JavaScript, this means explicitly don't allow anyone to View Source or View Generated Source or Debug to enable viewing your cipher key.

Exactly how would one completely obfuscate a cipher key in a web page? It is not possible to completely prevent someone from viewing the source, only make it inconvenient. Any encryption/decryption routines on the client can also be identified fairly easily.

What exactly is the suggested route we should take here?

Answer (score 2):

I am not familiar with pubnub, but in cases similar to this, you can create a hash or some other reference that points to the secret on your server.  So the hash is shared between client/server, and the server references the hash as your key.

You have not said what your server side language is, but there are a number of different hashing mechanisms available, SHA-1 or similar is recommended https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SHA-1

Answer (score 1):

That's exactly the point: you cannot ever publish your `cipher_key` on the web under any circumstances. Websites may use their API given the other (public) keys, but the cipher_key must only be used from environments that are secure.

Comment: Ok, appreciate the second set of eyes, I was just baffled that their security page would make such a recommendation and wanted to make sure I wasn't missing anything.

Comment: You can use the cipher_key on any device. The cipher_key is just a symmetric key used for encryption. What you need to ensure is that the cipher_key is transmitted securely from your server to device. You are not supposed to hard code your cipher_key.

Messages exchanged over a TLS session are encrypted using a symmetric key too. During the SSL/TLS handshake, public key techniques are used to agree on the symmetric key.

Also, cipher keys are only to be shared with trusted parties.